# serve different local json data with express js and vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, vue.js

I am very new in NodeJS and Expressjs. i have three json file in a folder called json-data and want to setup a simple nodejs app which is serve data and i can consume it on vuejs front-end. But i can not figure how can i Create a simple nodeJS app that can serve the data.

### Here is the task that i am trying to complete.

A call center makes tons of calls daily through call center agents and these calls are dumped in JSON files. We need you to handle this large amount of data, and present it in a nice way for the supervisors.

The issue with the data is the structure, it is spread across multiple files. i need to solve this issue and present the data in a useful way.

#### 1. The first part:

Create a simple nodeJS app that can serve the data. You can use any nodeJS framework for that. The data in `json-data` folder should not be changed.

#### 2. The second part:

Create an app which uses a modern JS frontend framework **Vue**. The frontend app should have these routes:

- `/` a home page to show an aggregated table for the calls, for ex:

  | Phone number | Number of calls | Last call details |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | +49151484522 | 3 calls | Agent name / 11:46 |
  | +49158544147 | 1 call | Agent name / 14:46 |
  | +49151783331 | 2 calls | Agent name / 16:46 |

  by clicking on the agent name it would go to the agent log

  by clicking on the **Phone number** it would go to that number log
- `/agent/${ID}` to show an agent specific call log, for ex:

  | Phone number | Call date and time | Resolution |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | +49151484522 | 22/1/2020 14:20:22 | need reschedule |
  | +49158544147 | 22/1/2020 16:54:12 | no response |
  | +49158544147 | 22/1/2020 17:54:12 | no response |
- `/call/${number}` to show call logs of a specific number

  | Agent Name | Call date and time | Resolution |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | John Bob | 22/1/2020 14:20:22 | need reschedule |
  | Chris Toms | 22/1/2020 17:54:12 | no response |
  | John Bob | 22/1/2020 17:54:12 | no response |

Three json file name and data is

```
agents.json
```

```js
[
  {
    "identifier": "28c6acec-9ee0-11e7-b66c-3cb9f33ef190",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "Johndoe@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/3366FF/FFFFFF?text=John.Doe"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "beb04834-9f8b-11e7-9469-8a39b455b609",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Bob",
    "email": "JohnBob@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/7EE833/333333?text=John.Bob"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "8273f480-a28b-11e7-b106-e7aa9bbee08e",
    "firstName": "Rose",
    "lastName": "Patterson",
    "email": "RosePatterson@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF805D/333333?text=Rose.Patterson"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "firstName": "Abraham",
    "lastName": "Ellis",
    "email": "Abraham.Ellis@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Rose.Patterson"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "e512594e-a34c-11e7-a6cb-0609e42722e2",
    "firstName": "Joel",
    "lastName": "Wagner",
    "email": "Joel.Wagner@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Joel.Wagner"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "9644e296-a8f1-11e7-b7d2-36bd3f24901a",
    "firstName": "Wilfred",
    "lastName": "Anderson",
    "email": "Wilfred.Anderson@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Wilfred.Anderson"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2900c694-a8f3-11e7-b119-b7844b927e5c",
    "firstName": "Delbert",
    "lastName": "Pena",
    "email": "Delbert.Pena@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Delbert.Pena"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "firstName": "Madeline",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "email": "Madeline.Lee@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Madeline.Lee"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "e86b789e-a8f3-11e7-b549-b60535cbd9d7",
    "firstName": "Morris",
    "lastName": "Chambers",
    "email": "Morris.Chambers@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Morris.Chambers"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2d28a260-a8f7-11e7-953a-4894ae2813ba",
    "firstName": "Albert",
    "lastName": "Roy",
    "email": "Albert.Roy@callcenter.xyz",
    "photo": "https://via.placeholder.com/300/E241BC/FFFFFF?text=Albert.Roy"
  }
]
```

```
logs.json
```

```js
[
  {
    "identifier": "f53b3e0e-6a21-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-05T14:48:00.000Z",
    "duration": 230
  },
  {
    "identifier": "0b96031e-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-06T13:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 93
  },
  {
    "identifier": "29b7189c-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 146
  },
  {
    "identifier": "44c18ef6-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "e512594e-a34c-11e7-a6cb-0609e42722e2",
    "number": "+49158544147",
    "dateTime": "2020-11-07T15:20:00.000Z",
    "duration": 7
  },
  {
    "identifier": "237d0a4e-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "e512594e-a34c-11e7-a6cb-0609e42722e2",
    "number": "+49158544147",
    "dateTime": "2020-11-08T16:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 146
  },
  {
    "identifier": "274c1818-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "e512594e-a34c-11e7-a6cb-0609e42722e2",
    "number": "+49158544147",
    "dateTime": "2020-11-09T17:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 189
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2c97e1b2-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151783331",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-10T18:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 71
  },
  {
    "identifier": "32cf8544-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151783331",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-11T10:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 286
  },
  {
    "identifier": "35dcfac8-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151783331",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-12T11:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 286
  },
  {
    "identifier": "39dfda28-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-02-01T15:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 269
  },
  {
    "identifier": "3d35d808-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-02-02T16:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 8
  },
  {
    "identifier": "4104b274-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49151514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-02-03T17:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 249
  },
  {
    "identifier": "9e905d3e-0884-4d38-8195-c5b73278876d",
    "agentIdentifier": "2900c694-a8f3-11e7-b119-b7844b927e5c",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-09-01T12:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 170
  },
  {
    "identifier": "730f0d87-030f-4d8d-b1de-686144ad8d73",
    "agentIdentifier": "e86b789e-a8f3-11e7-b549-b60535cbd9d7",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-09-01T13:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 247
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2d28a260-a8f7-11e7-953a-4894ae2813ba",
    "agentIdentifier": "6fe55f02-a8f3-11e7-b037-c33c31bca71f",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-09-01T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 254
  },
  {
    "identifier": "b84874bf-ea9c-4b85-a6dd-f0098ec84d25",
    "agentIdentifier": "8273f480-a28b-11e7-b106-e7aa9bbee08e",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-08-09T12:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 56
  },
  {
    "identifier": "8d06b645-5135-4689-891b-ccc4cab886b7",
    "agentIdentifier": "8273f480-a28b-11e7-b106-e7aa9bbee08e",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-08-10T10:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 67
  },
  {
    "identifier": "c93e2611-3a35-4820-9e0d-6bc7bd764118",
    "agentIdentifier": "8273f480-a28b-11e7-b106-e7aa9bbee08e",
    "number": "+49221514231",
    "dateTime": "2020-08-11T15:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 37
  },

  {
    "identifier": "9c5c0175-2ef7-4307-ab91-87cc1abfa235",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 16
  },
  {
    "identifier": "5ec271b1-d89c-4c5f-a552-e5d66562851a",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 118
  },
  {
    "identifier": "634ee4b1-d492-4f36-8114-f0e98fd63efe",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 63
  },
  {
    "identifier": "82f96e9e-0591-471f-8d79-0a0cb243e7e1",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 205
  },
  {
    "identifier": "1388b62e-3390-4dce-8f29-2dd714905f44",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 75
  },
  {
    "identifier": "38dead49-68de-4332-9089-4c4f519b460f",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 122
  },
  {
    "identifier": "e3092702-9374-4bd5-8265-c88173d5b252",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 209
  },
  {
    "identifier": "8ce10c54-24c5-430e-b667-22cd22f6e7d8",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 262
  },
  {
    "identifier": "c58b1210-985a-47be-a912-f401ff84c118",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 222
  },
  {
    "identifier": "47316182-1fdd-4d31-be81-020e0dc136d6",
    "agentIdentifier": "356b03dc-9ec5-11e7-97a6-d501104f897e",
    "number": "+49151484522",
    "dateTime": "2020-10-07T14:50:00.000Z",
    "duration": 15
  }
]
```

```
resoulation.json
```

```js
[
  {
    "identifier": "f53b3e0e-6a21-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "0b96031e-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "29b7189c-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "44c18ef6-6a22-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "237d0a4e-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "274c1818-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2c97e1b2-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "32cf8544-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "35dcfac8-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "39dfda28-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "3d35d808-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "4104b274-6a23-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "9e905d3e-0884-4d38-8195-c5b73278876d",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "730f0d87-030f-4d8d-b1de-686144ad8d73",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "2d28a260-a8f7-11e7-953a-4894ae2813ba",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "b84874bf-ea9c-4b85-a6dd-f0098ec84d25",
    "resolution": "need reschedule"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "8d06b645-5135-4689-891b-ccc4cab886b7",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "c93e2611-3a35-4820-9e0d-6bc7bd764118",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "9c5c0175-2ef7-4307-ab91-87cc1abfa235",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "5ec271b1-d89c-4c5f-a552-e5d66562851a",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "634ee4b1-d492-4f36-8114-f0e98fd63efe",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "82f96e9e-0591-471f-8d79-0a0cb243e7e1",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "1388b62e-3390-4dce-8f29-2dd714905f44",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "38dead49-68de-4332-9089-4c4f519b460f",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "e3092702-9374-4bd5-8265-c88173d5b252",
    "resolution": "no answer"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "8ce10c54-24c5-430e-b667-22cd22f6e7d8",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "c58b1210-985a-47be-a912-f401ff84c118",
    "resolution": "interested"
  },
  {
    "identifier": "47316182-1fdd-4d31-be81-020e0dc136d6",
    "resolution": "needs follow up"
  }
]
```

### Important notes:

- the data in `json-data` folder should not be changed!.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time developers.

Comment: Have a look at [express js](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) as it's a nodejs server that will easily do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the file system, it's good to use a database.

### Here a sample solution

1. Add the `json-data` folder to the root of this project.
2. Add `key.js` file in the root of this project

```js
module.exports = {
    PATH: "json-data",
    RESOULATION: "resoulation.json",
    AGENTS: "agents.json",
    LOGS: "logs.json",
}
```

3. Router file

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const CommonController = require("../controllers/common");

router.get("/", CommonController.home);
router.get("/agent/:id/", CommonController.agent);
router.get("/call/:number/", CommonController.call);

module.exports = router;
```

4. **Controllers File**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

const KEYS = require("../keys");

function get_logs(){
    let file_name = path.join(__dirname, `../${KEYS.PATH}`, KEYS.LOGS)
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(file_name);
    let logs = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    return logs;
}
function get_agents(){
    let file_name = path.join(__dirname, `../${KEYS.PATH}`, KEYS.AGENTS)
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(file_name);
    let agents = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    let data = {}
    agents.forEach(element => {
        data[element.identifier] = element
    });
    return data;
}
function get_regoulation(){
    let file_name = path.join(__dirname, `../${KEYS.PATH}`, KEYS.RESOULATION)
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(file_name);
    let agents = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    let data = {}
    agents.forEach(element => {
        data[element.identifier] = element.resolution
    });
    return data;
}

exports.home = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let logs = get_logs();
        let customData = {}
        logs.forEach(element => {
            if(!customData[element.number]){
                customData[element.number] = [element]
            }else{
                customData[element.number].push(element)
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "File Problem" });
    }
    let agent = get_agents();

    let result = [];
    try{
        for(const number in customData){
            const object = customData[number];
            const last = object[object.length-1];
            const _agent = agent[last.agentIdentifier];
            console.log(_agent, last.agentIdentifier)
            const data = {
                number,
                numberOfCall: object.length,
                name: _agent.firstName + " " + _agent.lastName,
                duration: last.duration
            };
            result.push(data);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Data Manupulation problem" });
    }
    res.status(200).json( result );
};

exports.agent = async (req, res, next) => {
    const ID = req.params.id;
    const result = []
    try{
        const regoulation = get_regoulation();
        const logs = get_logs();
        logs.forEach(element => {
            if (element.agentIdentifier==ID){
                result.push({
                    number: element.number,
                    dateTime: element.dateTime,
                    resolution: regoulation[element.identifier]
                })
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Data extracting problem" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(result);
};

exports.call = async (req, res, next) => {
    const NUMBER = req.params.number;
    const result = []
    try{
        const logs = get_logs();
        const agents = get_agents();
        const regoulation = get_regoulation();
        logs.forEach(element => {
            if (element.number==NUMBER){
                const agent = agents[element.agentIdentifier]
                result.push({
                    name: agent.firstName + " " + agent.lastName,
                    resolution: regoulation[element.identifier],
                    dateTime: element.dateTime,
                })
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Data extracting problem" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could load up all the JSON in memory on the express server and search for the data you are looking for on each request.

Realistically, that would be really inefficient if you had much larger files. It would imply that every request would load the JSON into memory. Also searching through large objects is expensive.

Ideally you would store the entries in a database. If you can't or don't have the need to use a database for storing this data, you could index it with some kind of search engine. There are a few lightweight search engines that you could use on the server.
A quick Google search brought this one up: https://lunrjs.com/
Though I haven't personally used it.